# Azure Data Factory - Storing the entire response of a Http call

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any mechanism in the ADF world, where I can store the entire response as a text file in a storage container? I am facing multiple issues with nested arrays and their mapping.

Issue #1. When I make a call to a webservice, the webservice returns an XML, but ADF insists on converting that to JSON.

Issue #2. The JSON that ADF creates has a nested array and I am unable to map that array to a text file.

My current need is to store the response from the webservice call in a storage container in a file.

Example JSON that ADF creates:

```
[
  {
    "PaymentRequest": {
      "ID": "PR123",
      "VendorRemitAddress": {
        "Address1": "PLAZA DE MARIO",
        "City": "Compton",
        "State": "CA",
        "PostalCode": 90221,
        "CountryCode": "US"
      },
      "LineItems": {
        "LineItem": [
          {
            "LineItemId": "62",
            "ExpenseTypeCode": "PAP123",
            "RequestLineItemNumber": 2,
            "Quantity": 1.0,
            "UnitPrice": 330.0,
            "TotalPrice": 330.0
          },
          {
            "LineItemId": "75",
            "ExpenseTypeCode": "WOD123",
            "RequestLineItemNumber": 1,
            "Quantity": 2.0,
            "UnitPrice": 10.0,
            "TotalPrice": 20.0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Use dataflow activity to flatten the nested Json and then map to the file

Comment: DataFlow activity cannot accept HttpCall as a source. Have you tried this out? It grays out the Httpcall.

Comment: In copy activity itself, you can try this in mapping 
1. Import schemas. 2. Switch on the advanced editor. 3. Give the collection reference value 4. Give the mapping from source to sink. Refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/pT4M319.png)

Answer (score 2):

In order to store the entire nested response from the webservice call to a storage container file, we should toggle the advanced editor in the mapping section of copy activity and give the appropriate collection reference value.
I tried to repro this in my environment. Below are the steps.

- A sample http (xml response) web data is taken.
  [image]
- I have added this XML file as source dataset using HTTP connector in copy data activity.
- When preview data is clicked in source dataset, the Json representation of xml response can be viewed. [image]
- I have added a delimited text file in azure blob storage as a sink dataset.
- In mapping,

  1. **Import schemas** is selected.
  2. **Advanced editor** is switched to on.
  3. Array Value from which the data needs to be unrolled and extracted is given in **collection reference**. [ In your sample data, `$['PaymentRequest']['LineItems']['LineItem']` will be the value in collection reference. Because for the payment request id, every lineitem needs to be iterated and extracted.]
  4. Mapping is given from source to sink.[image]
- Once the pipeline is run, data is copied into sink and the output file looks as in below image.[image]

Comment: Hi Aswin, Thank you for your effort in answering this question. I don't wish to have a CSV file, I wish to store the entire json response. Ideally I would like to store the XML response, but since ADF will convert to JSON, I am happy storing the JSON response from the webservice.

Comment: Try Storing the json response as such in blob in staging container and then from flatten it using data flow activity.